# how to fetch events data from LinkedIn APIs?

Tags: api, events, linkedin-api

I am trying to fetch events data through LinkedIn API, but its throwing this error even I passed access token in my header. One more thing I am using postman to create API calls.

I am using this url to call API:-

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/events

{
"serviceErrorCode": 0,
"message": "Resource events does not exist",
"status": 404
}

I am rather new to working with these complex APIs, please help me

I read some more about it and it's written there that one need some special permissions to use event data ."r_events_leadgen_automation" permission is required. But how to get this permission, there is nothing on the docs about this.

[image]

Comment: It actually exists. Go to the URL now and you'll see it says: `{"serviceErrorCode":65604,"message":"Empty oauth2 access token","status":401}`

Comment: if you are going directly to the url then you are not passing the access token in authorization header ,that's why this happens, see the message carefully

Comment: Oh yeah. So I can't see the error unless I have a token. I don't like LinkedIn that much and I'm not requesting access to the API. I'm not sure then. Hopefully someone else would help...

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an app and then request access to the *Marketing Developer Platform* under the `Permissions` tab. However, getting this access is not easy. You need to fill out and submit a detailed form asking questions about your business and what you intend to do with the access. And you may need to ask for more access after all. I have never gone that far.

You can find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/getting-started?view=li-lms-2022-06).